# Dynamic Variable Names in LESS CSS

Tags: css, less

I have been trying this for a while, looking at other answers, but to no avail. Hopefully someone can help me.

I am trying to generate some dynamic variable names within a mixin.

The variables are already defined:

```
@horizontal-default-color: #fff;
@horizontal-inverse-color: #000;
```

etc..

The mixin I want would be something like this:

```
.horizontal-variant(@variant) {
    color: @{horizontal-@{@variant}-color}
}
```

And the result I am expecting, when called:

```
.horizontal-default{
   .horizontal-variant(~"default");
}
.horizontal-inverse{
   .horizontal-variant(~"inverse");
}
```

is

```
.horizontal-default {color: #fff}
.horizontal-inverse {color: #000}
```

Unfortunately I run into errors every time.

I know this can be done, I have seen it being used in Font Awesome LESS where `@{fa-css-prefix}` is defined in variables. I am just having trouble transporting the same solution in my project.

You can try testing the code at http://lesstester.com/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use **[Variable Names](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names)**. And I've tested the code at http://lesstester.com/, it works.

```
@horizontal-default-color: #fff;
@horizontal-inverse-color: #000;

.horizontal-variant(@variant) {
  @color: "horizontal-@{variant}-color";
  color: @@color;
}

.horizontal-default{
  .horizontal-variant(default);
}
.horizontal-inverse{
  .horizontal-variant(inverse);
}
```

Comment: How about being able to set default values too? I mean I'd like my variable to be created with some default value to be later overridden. Is it posible after all?

Comment: @kboom Yes, you can do that just like this: https://gist.github.com/Witcher42/e58c814de05c0fb49678#file-vnwdv-less

Comment: I mean I'd like to skip @ horizontal-default-color: #fff;
@ horizontal-inverse-color: #000; definitions. I'd like less to create such variables for me when I do something like .horizontal-variant(45px) - then I would get something like @horizontal-variant: 45dx without really creating such variable. Then I would get something to be later overriden without effort to define it myself.