# how to use recursive definition in less?

Tags: css, less

I want to obtain a variable through another one.

```
@index:2;
@theme1-color: #2d8cf0, #19be6b, #515a6e, #363e4f, rgba(255,255,255,.7);
@theme2-color: #2d8cf0, #89bf04, #89bf04, #89bf04, #89bf04;

@primary-color          : extract(@{theme@{index}-color},1);
```

What's wrong with my code? Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Variable Names in LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823833/dynamic-variable-names-in-less-css)

Comment: yeah...it's duplicated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Witcher42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23824424/4306572) you can use Variable Names.

```
@index: 2;
@theme1-color: #2d8cf0, #19be6b, #515a6e, #363e4f, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
@theme2-color: #2d8cf0, #89bf04, #89bf04, #89bf04, #89bf04;

@primary-color: "theme@{index}-color";

a {
  color: extract(@@primary-color, 1);
}
```