# How to get color values by class in Less?

Tags: css, less

Example I have exist **class** like

```
.color-white {
   color : #fff;
   //background: #fff; <-- or getting by background
}
```

It could be located in third-party .css file.

And in Less how to get color `#fff` ?

**Somthing like**

```
.hello {
   color : getColorByClass(.color-white);
}
```

or

```
@white : getColorByClass(.color-white);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Use variables? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198221/defining-variable-variables-using-less-css

Comment: hm ?, Did you mean `@white : #fff;` ? If yes , i already know @DarrenSweeney

Comment: I guess it depends what else is in the class - you could always use `.hello { &:extend(.color-white); }`

Comment: Thanks so much, This should be another way I would do.

Answer (score 1):

So to not leave this unanswered. The answer is *"No, it's impossible"*.

Simply because the primary purpose of Less is to help to write a new and not to hack an existing CSS code.

---

Technically, there're some features planned that will make this possible (more like a side-effect rather than a primarily aim again). But yet again, w/o knowing what your actual goal was and what kind of problem you tried to solve, it's difficult to say if such feature would be a proper way to solve it (suspecting an XY-Problem as always).