# Append an argument to a variable in a LESS mixin

Tags: css, variables, less, preprocessor

Here's the code I have:

```
@color-level-1: #99FFDD;
@color-level-2: #4484F6;
@color-level-3: #E91E63;
@color-level-4: #E99D1E;
@color-level-5: #D51EE9;


.some-color(@i) {
  + .some-class-name {
    background-color: @color-level-@i;
  }
}

.another-class-name {
  .some-color(3);
}
```

What is trying to accomplish is getting this output when using the mixin:

```
.another-class-name + .some-class-name {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work. What I am getting as an output is:

```
.another-class-name + .some-class-name {
  background-color:  3;
}
```

I've tried escaping, but it does not help as well. Does someone have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: I think you can put the colours in a list and then use it in the code http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining Variable Variables using LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198221/defining-variable-variables-using-less-css)

Comment: @chazsolo Thanks man, I've tried searching for near an hour, but I did not find this thread. It works!

Comment: The soluton is `@color-name: "color-level-@{i}"; background-color: @@color-name;`

Comment: @3rdthemagical solution works as well.

Comment: @MindPhuq It would be nice if you wrote your solution. To not leave a question without an answer.

Comment: @3rdthemagical thanks for noting this. I've updated the thread with an answer.

Comment: Don't emulate arrays/lists with the ugly variable-name-string-concatenation-bla-bla-ba, this is just ridiculous. Less has [native lists support](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first one is:

```css
@color-level-1: #99FFDD;
@color-level-2: #4484F6;
@color-level-3: #E91E63;
@color-level-4: #E99D1E;
@color-level-5: #D51EE9;

.some-color(@i) {
  + .some-class-name {
    background-color: ~"@{color-level-@{i}}";
  }
}

.another-class-name {
  .some-color(3);
}
```

And the second is:

```css
@color-level-1: #99FFDD;
@color-level-2: #4484F6;
@color-level-3: #E91E63;
@color-level-4: #E99D1E;
@color-level-5: #D51EE9;

.some-color(@i) {
  + .some-class-name {
    @color-name: "color-level-@{i}";
    background-color: @@color-name;
  }
}

.another-class-name {
  .some-color(3);
}
```

Both of these return:

```css
.another-class-name + .some-class-name {
  background-color: #E91E63;
}
```